# get color of each pixel from sl::zed::Mat

Tags: mat, getpixel, getvalue, getcolor

i have a variable sl::zed::Mat and i want to get color of each pixel from that Mat. i was tried using getValue(x,y) to get 3 channels, but i can't get reach the value over 50.

here's my codes:

```
sl::zed::Mat color = data->_color;
sl::uchar3 bgrPixel = color.getValue(i, j);
```

i'm really confused, are they the right color or not? or you have another way to get color from each pixel of that variable type?